# About clean install

Tags: windows

I tried to install some Windows updates yesterday and I got a BSoD kernel data inpage. 
After that I couldn't boot windows anymore. Safe mode neither. 
I waited a few hours and tried again to boot windows but no success.  This time I got unmountable boot volume which is not the first time because I accidentally deleted some Windows registry keys. 
I currently run programs like Hirens boot cd to find out what's the problem and maybe fix it but I think I'll need to do a clean install.  It would be the first time but I saw tutorials and I think I can manage. 
There are only 2 questions I want an answer.
1. When I bought the laptop there were some programs installed. I don't exactly know what programs because I never used them. Or at least that's what I think.  Maybe my laptop used them somehow..?
From your experience how did you recover those programs after clean install?
Also if you know any ways to fix the error without clean install I'm opened to suggestions. I do not really like the idea of clean install but somebody suggested I have a corrupted boot partition or something like that or there is certainly something missing. 
Startup Repair didn't work.

Comment: Hi Iris. Please limit each question post to a single question, preferably which can be objectively and authoritatively answered. (I recommend that you simply **[edit]** your question to fix that.) Also, unfortunately, product recommendation questions are off-topic on Super User. You may have some luck with the second question on [softwarerecs.se], but *make sure to read their guidelines* for what makes an acceptable question to avoid it being closed there.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a clean install, you do not retain the programs that your computer came with. But almost certainly you have not used them. In fact, many people do a clean install specifically to get rid of them!

If the problem is in fact a corrupt bootloader and you have the install cd, this might work:
Boot to the install cd, choose "repair your computer", open command prompt and type "bootrec /FixMBR" without quotations. If that doesn't work, it sounds like it's time for a clean install.

Keep in mind: After a clean install, you will **not keep** any of your personal files, programs or even drivers. You might want to try to backup your files first. Your programs you will just have to reinstall, and your drivers can be re-downloaded from the manufacturer's site.